# Not able to deploy EJB in WebLogic server 12c

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic, jndi, weblogic12c

I have created a EJB, created a jar of it( containing required ejb-jar.xml and weblogic-ejb-jar.xml files).

when i add this jar to weblogic server 12c, using admin console, i get following issue-

```
Issues were encountered while parsing this deployment to determine module type. Assuming this is a library deployment.
```

Due to this my ejb is not shown in jndi tree view. So I am not able to do my jndi lookup. Please rectify my error.

ejb-jar.xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ejb-jar PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Enterprise JavaBeans 2.0//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/ejb-jar_2_0.dtd">
<ejb-jar id="ejb-jar_ID">
    <display-name>ProductManager</display-name>
    <enterprise-beans>
    <session>
    <ejb-name>Product</ejb-name>    
    <home>rohit.ProductHome</home>
    <remote>rohit.ProductRemote</remote>
    <ejb-class>rohit.ProductBean</ejb-class>    
    <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
    <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
    </session>  
    </enterprise-beans>
    <ejb-client-jar>ProductManagerClient.jar</ejb-client-jar>

</ejb-jar>
```

weblogic-ejb-jar.xml-

```
<?xml version=“1.0? encoding=“UTF-8??>
<weblogic-ejb-jar

xmlns=“http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90? xmlns:j2ee=“http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee” xmlns:xsi=“http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance” xsi:schemaLocation=“http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90 http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90/weblogic-ejb-jar.xsd”>

<welogic-enterprise-bean>
<ejb-name>Product</ejb-name>
<jndi-name>Product</jndi-name>
<stateless-session-descriptor></stateless-session-descriptor>
</welogic-enterprise-bean>
</weblogic-ejb-jar>
```

Comment: Please guys, i need some help here.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to what you seem to be thinking, the ejb-jar.xml and weblogic-ejb-jar.xml files are not required. As primary deployment descriptors they are ancient artifacts from 2004.

Your `ProductHome` class should also be removed if you value your sanity. This is an EJB2 artifact that's completely and utterly unnecessary this time of age.

To get started with EJB, all you need is a POJO with an `@Stateless` annotation:

```
@Stateless
public class ProductBean {
    // ...
}
```

Jar this up and deploy it. That's all. You don't have to explicitly name your bean (it will get a name) and you certainly don't have to declare its existence in some XML file.

Answer (score 0):

The ejb-jar.xml is mandatory when deploying an application as a jar file. The correct place to put it is in the META-INF in the jar.

Yes, annotations are definitely nice and easier to maintain. Try this by leaving the ejb-jar.xml minimal.

I always package my applications in EAR with the jars inside. In this case an application.xml file is needed.

It sounds like the container does not recognize the jar as an application. Check the position of the ejb-jar.xml or use EAR packaging.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle recommends that even standalone EJBs be packed as an EAR file. The EJB descriptors should be inside the META-INF of the ejb-module.
See this link for the EAR structure for more details.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/splitcreate.htm#i1103260